# Determining app state when `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController` are displayed and dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uialertview, uialertcontroller

When a privacy alert is shown in iOS (for example asking for access to Photos), `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` is called as the alert is displayed and the app becomes inactive. Then when a choice is made on the alert and the app resumes, `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is called. This is also the case when other alerts are shown for example when a notifications alert is displayed i.e. `registerUserNotificationSettings`.

***However***, when calling an **`UIAlertView`** or **`UIAlertController`**, `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` are not called when the focus changes from the app to the alert.

> **Question:**
>
> What is going on? What is the equivalent notifications triggered for
>   the application’s inactive and active state when `UIAlertView` or
>   `UIAlertController` are displayed and dismissed?

Comment: If you need to execute some code when UIAlertView or UIAlertController are displayed or dismissed you can just use the completion handler in the displayViewController call and UIAlertAction calls, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

When your own code explicitly displays a `UIAlertController` (or `UIAlertView`), there is no notification. Your app already knows you are showing the alert because you just showed it.

Other system alerts, like the privacy alerts, are not shown by your app. They are shown by iOS. That is the difference. Your app isn't active because the OS has now active showing the alert. Your app becomes active again when the system alert is done.

Comment: Thanks, @rmaddy . But is there a change of view, subviews or layout that can be tapped in to when it is displayed and prevents all other interactions?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Let me clarify. When `UIAlertController` or `UIAlertView` are displayed, interaction with the rest of the app is prevented. `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `viewWillAppear`, aren't triggered either. Is there is absolutely nothing that occurs to the view hierarchy when the alerts are displayed by the app itself?

Comment: Certainly no layout changes are made. viewWillDisappear might be in the controller presenting the alert.

Comment: Thanks, @rmaddy I'll look further into it.